# Reliable way(s) of finding home directory of Sybase DB (ASE) on Linux and Windows

Tags: linux, windows, sybase, sybase-ase

I need to write a script that finds Sybase installation on a system if there's any.

For testing I've installed ASE 16 on CentOS system, but the installer is apparently based on InstallAnywhere (Java).

This is one of the installation methods apparently, I'm not sure if there are more ways to install ASE like installing RPM package.

Anyway, there's this `SYBASE.sh` script for sourcing environment variables in the ASE installation that contains home directory. It's obviously catch-22 situation: in order to find this script I need to know the home directory of ASE to start with.

Yes, I can check in the usual locations like `/sysdba` or `/opt/sap`. The interactive installer obviously allows ASE to be installed anywhere of course, so that's not good enough.

What's the best way to find it? I'm willing to do stuff like tracking running processes to their executables etc., just anything that would help me find where ASE is installed. For reasons I won't go into even finding it just when it's running would be good.

I can run the script as root or Administrator, no problems with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In linux the ASE binary is called `dataserver` so you could search for this when perusing running processes and/or running a `find`.

`dataserver` is going to be found under `$SYBASE/$SYBASE_ASE/bin` where:

- `$SYBASE` is considered the `'ASE home directory'` and is typically something like `/opt/sybase`, `/opt/sap` though as you've pointed out it can be anything the user wants
- `$SYBASE_ASE` is going to be of the format `ASE-15_0` or `ASE-16_0`; this is a default directory created by the ASE software installation script (ie, the user does not decide this directory's name)

So, if you find the location of the `dataserver` binary then you should be able to work up from that to determine `$SYBASE` (and `$SYBASE_ASE`).

In the `$SYBASE` (home) directory you're also going to find files named `SYBASE.sh`, `SYBASE.csh` and `interfaces` (though `interfaces` could be a symlink if the DBA is sharing a common file among multiple Sybase installations on the same host).

And, yeah, it's possible to have multiple ASE installations (ie, multiple `$SYBASE` directories) on the same host.

---

As for the question (?) about methods of installation ...

The only method that comes with the software is a java-based program (w/ GUI and CLI interfaces).

In larger environments it's quite possible the DBA and/or sysadmin groups have created their own installation 'package' (eg, a tarball created from a pre-configured ASE installation) but that's going to be site specific.